# Qt two classes use each other

Tags: qt, class

Hello I have two classes `Zonk` and `Orfina`, and I want have an object at each of these classes. My code look as follows:

```
#ifndef ZONK_H
#define ZONK_H

class Zonk;

class Orfina
{
    Zonk zonkmm;
};



class Zonk
{
    Orfina orfina;
public:
    Zonk();
};

#endif // ZONK_H
```

When I try to compile I get an error:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\test\zonk.h:8: error: field 'zonkmm' has incomplete type
 Zonk zonkmm;
      ^
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - Forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pointers in the declaration, and include the headers in the definitions.

```
//Orfina.hpp
class Zonk;
class Orfina
{
Zonk* zonkmm;

public:

};

//Zonk.hpp
class Orfina;
class Zonk
{
    Orfina* orfina;
public:
    Zonk();
};

// Orfina.cpp
#include "Zonk.hpp"

// Zonk.cpp
#include "Orfina.hpp"
```